# Updating nodejs in Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: node.js, meteor, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I've been trying to deploy a meteor project (leaderboard example) to Amazons Elastic Beanstalk. I used the ebconfiguration script found at  https://gist.github.com/fightingtheboss/5432059 and edited the ROOT_URL and NodeVersion as well as having added a MONGO_URI and DISABLE_WEBSOCKETS variable. After all this, meteor complains that it needs at least node v0.10.21, and after checking I see that despite the fact that I specified 0.10.21 in BOTH the configuration script and the console, the server prints out that it's running nodejs v0.8.24. I've tried updating by specifying it through the yum block, manually downloading the latest version of node and moving it to /usr/local/ as well as downloading the source and compiling. None of these worked, the server insists on that it runs node v0.8.24. **Does anyone know how to update nodejs on Elastic Beanstalk to at least v0.10.21?**

Comment: Check if `sudo node --version` and `node --version` give different outputs. Also how did you initially install node was it using yum? Is your instance built on amazon linux?

Comment: It doesn't let me run sudo node --version, states that I need tty to run sudo.

Answer (score 2):

Steps to update node version in EB.

1. Go to the EB console
2. Select your environment
3. Select Configuration from the left side menu
4. Click on the setting icon of Software Configuration
5. Change the node version 0.8.24 to 0.10.21
6. Hit Save button located at the bottom right corner.

The process may take few minutes.

Answer (score -1):

How old is your elastic beanstalk container?  If it was originally created several months ago there are limits as to which version of node that can be run within that container (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/concepts.platforms.html).

If it is not the above, when you upgrade via the console does the console show your version as being 0.10.21?

Comment: The container was created the same day, and no matter what action I took, it always reported 0.8.24.

Answer (score -1):

According to this document, the most recent version of Node supported in EB is 0.10.10:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_nodejs.container.html

**edit:** As Chris states though, 0.10.21 is supposed to be supported however in my experience I've only gotten 0.10.10 to work successfully using the methods you describe.